# find previous max index in data frame with conditional statement

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

From a dataset like this, I need to find the maximum closest previous index for A. The data frame may be large, but it always must find the last previous index where the second column is equal to "A".

```
index  X
1     A
2     B
3     C
4     D
5     E
6     A
7     B
8     C
9     D
10    E
```

Here is the output that I am looking to achieve. The maximum closest previous index for "A"

```
index  X    Y
1     A    1
2     B    1
3     C    1
4     D    1
5     E    1
6     A    6
7     B    6
8     C    6
9     D    6
10    E    6
```

Something like this.

```
  for i in x: 
      max(if df[i][1] == 'A' and df[0] < df[i][0]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the index column where X is 'A' using where:

```
In [11]: df['index'].where(df['X'] == 'A')
Out[11]:
0     1
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
5     6
6   NaN
7   NaN
8   NaN
9   NaN
Name: index, dtype: float64
```

It looks like you just want to ffill this:

```
In [12]: df['index'].where(df['X'] == 'A').ffill()
Out[12]:
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    6
6    6
7    6
8    6
9    6
Name: index, dtype: float64
```

and setting this to column Y gets you the desired result:

```
In [13]: df['Y'] = df['index'].where(df['X'] == 'A').ffill()
```